# Почему получаю FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java, android, zip

Прочитываю архив `zip` с помощью такого класса

```
public class Decompress {
private String zipFile;
private String location;
private final String MY_LOG = "Decompress";

public Decompress(String zipFile, String location) {
    this.zipFile = zipFile;
    this.location = location;
    dirChecker(location.replace(".zip", ""));
}

public void unzip() {
    try  {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(fin);
        ZipEntry ze;

        while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            Log.e(MY_LOG, "Unzipping " + ze.getName());

            if(ze.isDirectory()) {
                dirChecker(ze.getName());
            } else {
                write(zis, new FileOutputStream(location.replace(".zip", "") + ze.getName()));
                zis.closeEntry();
            }
        }
        zis.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(MY_LOG, "unzip", e);
    }
}

private void write(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;

    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    out.close();
}

private void dirChecker(String dir) {
    File f = new File(location + dir);
    if(!f.isDirectory()) {
        f.mkdirs();
    }
}
```

И вот не могу понять, что за мистика тут происходит

Как видно в конструкторе я передаю `zipfile` это путь к тому файлу который нужно разархивировать и `location` это путь куда это все разархивировать

```
location - /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo/files/ttt@gmail.com/AvatarModelDir/new.zip

zipfile - /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo/files/yyyyy@gmail.com/AvatarModelDir/My.zip
```

Идея такая , что в той же директории рядом с `zip` архивом все должно разархивироваться.

так вот когда в методе `unzip()` выполняется метод

```
write(zis, new FileOutputStream(location + ze.getName()));
```

то создается папка в директории `/yyyyy@gmail.com/`

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo/files/yyyyy@gmail.com/AvatarModelDirAnna/Anna.dae
```

и уже в ней создаются файлы

Как сделать так, чтоб разархивация происходила на одном уровне, там же где и находится архив. А не как сейчас в `/yyyyy@gmail.com/` дириктории и к имени вложеной директории прибавляется имя из архива `/AvatarModelDirAnna/`

Я так понял, что проблема в этом методе

```
private void dirChecker(String dir) {
    File f = new File(location + dir);
    if(!f.isDirectory()) {
        f.mkdirs();
    }
}
```

Не пойму что он делает во всей этой конструкции... Он как бы создает путь, но зачем? Почему нельзя его сразу передать...

Я попробовал его вырезать и передавать путь сразу в метод

```
write(zis, new FileOutputStream(**path**));
```

но все поламалось...

Как сделать так, чтоб я мог передать путь куда разархивировать и туда все разархивировалось?

Comment: И где ты получаешь `FileNotFoundException`?

Comment: @DimTeam, Наверно когда вырезал код с созданием папок. Что сделано зря ведь не факт что такие папки есть

Comment: А что бы работало, как надо, во первых в конструкторе вызывайте dirChecker и передавайте ему имя архива без расширения. И вот эту строку: write(zis, new FileOutputStream(location + ze.getName())); тоже переделать. Между location и именем файла имя архива без расширения и все.

Comment: @DimTeam Я поменял код с нескольких местах, а именно путь `location` который я передаю, в конструкоре в метод `dirChecker()` я теперь передаю `location.replace(".zip", "")` и при вызове метода `write(zis, new FileOutputStream(location.replace(".zip", "") + ze.getName()));` я тоже первый агрумент передаю location.replace(".zip", "") .  А `FileNotFoundException` я получаю как раз в этом методе `write()`

Comment: @МаксимДробышев Я поменял код с нескольких местах, а именно путь location который я передаю, в конструкоре в метод dirChecker() я теперь передаю location.replace(".zip", "") и при вызове метода write(zis, new FileOutputStream(location.replace(".zip", "") + ze.getName())); я тоже первый агрумент передаю location.replace(".zip", "") . А FileNotFoundException я получаю как раз в этом методе write()

Comment: @МаксимДробышев Вроде все правильно сделал, но все равно если я в методе `write()` хоть как то меняю содержание `location` то сразу получаю `FileNotFoundException` .... Не пойму к чему привязывается этот путь что так реагирует на любые корректировки

Comment: @МаксимДробышев подскажите что нужно поменять, что я мог просто передать путь куда сохранять и все там сохранлось?